# How do I identify between new and edit actions in javascript rails?

Tags: webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I have got the webpack setup, so I am hiding certain elements on new action. But I don't want to do the same in the edit action. Since there is no way for me to pass instance variables to the js, I am kind of stuck.

I preferably don't want to go via the route of checking, if the url has "edit" to accomplish this. Is there a rails way to do this?

I would like to know if there is any convention in rails to do this

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I can write to a data attribute in the view, and the javascript can read from that view to determine whether it's new or edit.

If the view uses, `@model.persisted?` when new is rendered. It will put true in the view and false for edit